# Android Development Tutorials - "New Member In Activity" in HelloFormStuff

Tags: android

I am working my way through the tutorials at [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RadioButtons), and have come across a question that I am sure truly shows my newbie status.  In step 2 of ['Radio Buttons'](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RadioButtons) in the HelloFormStuff section of the HelloViews tutorial, I am directed to *"add the following code to create a new member in the HelloFormStuff Activity: "* ... What does that mean?
Do i add another class to the package? (new class dialog in eclipse grays out option for private class)
Do I insert somewhere inside the class HelloFormStuff? (error given: *"Illegal modifier for parameter radio_listener; only final is permitted"*
Thank you for any help you may provide.

Comment: The code @Nanne describes below will work for this application you're referencing in your post. However to answer "What does that mean" When your instructed to add anything, a member, call.. whatever to your classes Activity. Basically your adding code below the onCreate method for your activity (Class file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `radio_listener` is the new member. A member is like a part of the the class.

So pasting the provided code into the class is actually creating the new member.

It will look something like this (not tested, just read it as "pseudocode" please :) )

```
class HelloFormStuff extends Activity{

    //other stuff 

     private OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Perform action on clicks
           RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
           Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     };

   //other stuff, like onCreate();

}
```

Comment: I see ...  it seems that every time i was putting the code in the class HelloFormStuff, i was also nesting it _inside_ onCreate ... fixed that and all the errors went away! Thank You.

Comment: win! :) The error makes more sense too. Inside a method like `onCreate()` you cannot declare somthing `private`. You can however declare it static.